# Trouble port forwarding on ZTE F688 router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

I’ve been trying to make a Raspberry Pi 4 Minecraft server for my friends and read I need to port forward but my router (ZTE F688) doesn’t register the fact that I port forwarded.

Websites like YouGetSignal still says the port is closed odd thing is I can join on my home internet but when my friends try to join they can’t

[image]
I’ve tried:

- Rebooting the router
- Going to my ISP page on how to port forward
- Changing the WAN host address from 0000 to other numbers
- Setting using the Raspberry  Pi static IP
- Even DMZ doesn’t work

this is how I've been doing can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
and if I'm not wrong im behind a cgnat

Comment: Are you behind a CGNAT? [Edit] your question to include the necessary information to diagnose your issue

Comment: Please also add, How you have done the port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

> if I'm not wrong im behind a cgnat

If you're behind a CGNAT, then you're not able to receive connections. Anything you try to do in the router is irrelevant – to be able to forward packets, your router must first *receive* the packets that it's meant to forward, and that's not happening through CGNAT.

Comment: are there anyways to bypass this?

Comment: a) Call your ISP and ask for a "static IP address" (which implies a non-CGNAT one), or b) set up a VPN tunnel outbound to some other system that'll relay for you.